# What Stack Exchange site would be best for someone who's thinking about building their first PC?

Tags: discussion

Please advise.  PC Mag recommends a sister site called [ExtremeTech.com](http://ExtremeTech.com), but I'm wondering if there's a member of the Stack Exchange family that would be appropriate.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably superuser.com. Most definitely not serverfault.com.

Comment: Definitely superuser, but keep in mind that none of the stackexchange sites will do your work for you, and none of them will give shopping reccomendations.  You can't start from scratch - ask direct, concise questions about specific aspects of a build, not something like "should I go amd or intel", or "how do I get started".  We need more direction.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I know how it works.  I've got a shopping list, and I realize that I'll have to do the work.  I wasn't planning on calling you to stop by my house or anything.  Honestly....

Answer (score 0):

if really on the stackexchange I would go by the purpose of your PC. Superuser might be a good generic place.

If you go to to serverfault people will most likely be able to comment on Server type build.

Gaming PC  , again there is stackexchange for gamers. so pick yours.

Superuser would be the best IMO